# outsiderec.setFill(Color rgb(100, x, 0) - Syntax error?

Tags: python

Trying to use a randomized variable to randomize the color? Getting a syntax error.  Is this possible? 
Here's the rest of the code if that helps at all:

```
import graphics
import random
window= graphics.GraphWin("x", 600, 400)
stripes = input("How many stripes should be on the flag")
stripes = int(stripes)
count = 0
count = int(count)
P1=graphics.Point(0,0) #left corner - anchor point
for x in range(stripes): #loop for division of flag
    col= random.randint(1,255)
    stepdim = 400/stripes #size of divisions
    shrink = count*stepdim
    stepdim = int(stepdim)
    stepdim = stepdim*10 #enlarge to an increment below the last
    stepdim = stepdim-shrink
    stepdim = int(stepdim)
    P2=graphics.Point(600,stepdim) #bottom right corner - ever shrinking
    outsiderec=graphics.Rectangle(P1,P2) #
    outsiderec.setFill(Color rgb(100, col, 0)
    outsiderec.draw(window)
    count= count + 1
    count= int(count)
window.getMouse()
window.close()
```

python 3.4 if that's any help.

[image]

Comment: You need to close the other bracket on that line.

Comment: wow. @PakkuDon Bonehead error but it's still persisting after the fix.

Comment: @Kasra yes. I'll post a picture of the error if that's any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you want to use [**custom color**](http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/graphics.html#custom-colors) , you need to use `color_rgb(100, col, 0)` instead of `Color rgb(100, col, 0)`

Note first import `color_rgb` : `from graphics import color_rgb`

Comment: That gives NameError: name 'color_rgb' is not defined.

Comment: exq ... first import `color_rgb` !

Comment: There we go. Thanks a lot.